# Spectra from Temperature and Emission Measure

Tags: spectra

Having the solar flare fluxes on the two bands of GOES (0.05-0.4 nm and 0.1-0.8 nm) I need to calculate the flux between 0.05 and 0.2 nm.

Comment: By "emission measure profiles" it sounds like you mean the run of emission measure (amount of material times density) as a function of temperature, so that would not be a separate issue from the temperature itself.  Or do you mean you have a single temperature, and are imagining that the amount of gas times the density is just a single number at that temperature?  Either way, getting the spectrum is a difficult research-level task, often involving public software packages like XSPEC.  There's no easy way.